# HighStock Chart don't display line for missing Y axis data

Tags: javascript, plugins, highcharts

I want to display live real data in a highstock chart.
But there is no data during the weekend.
Meaning I have data on Friday evening and Monday morning.
I don't want these points to connect between them.
This is what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/rov8zu98/1/

```
[1236902400000,null],
[1237161600000,13.63],
```

I need a discontinued line, but null - is not ok as it also inserts a point on x axis

The thing is that I want to not display that GAP, so I want to hide it.

here is a mock-up of what I have and what I want to achieve:
[image: DesiredResult]

As you see - I want Monday to start right after Friday ends.

Again - the image is a mock-up.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are saying about `null`. Will you NOT be adding null values to the chart? So you will just have two points with some days difference in timestamp, and you want them to appear close, but disconnected? The JSFiddle has lots of `null`s. Will those not be there?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding 1 null value at the same timestamp as the first value of Monday. That seems to do what you want.

```
/* Mar 2009 */
[1237161600000,null], // An extra null value the same time as Monday 
[1237161600000,13.63],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nicholasduffy/rov8zu98/2/

Comment: the problem here is that the time between those dates is visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [gapSize](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.line.gapSize) option.

```
plotOptions: {
        line: {
            gapSize: 1
        }
    },
```

Comment: this is a good one, but still the gap persists, I need it without GAP, but interrupted line

Comment: But this is wrong - your chart will suggest that previous segment ends where new line-segment start, which would indicate exactly the same date, which is incorrect.